# CKEditor text color button not changing text color

Tags: ckeditor

I just installed the full version of CKEdiitor on a web page, and it works perfectly except for the change font color button and the background color button.

When used in the CKEditor it changes the text, but then when the changes are uploaded the color changes are not kept. Bold, Italic, all other formatting works perfectly!

I am using bootstrap3.

Is this a bug, or is there a setting I might need to investigate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `contents.css` in page, where you want to show CKEditor's text.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path to../ckeditor/contents.css">
```